# Sort List<T> into multilevel category navigation for DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Let me begin by illustrating what I have vs goal I'm trying to achieve

[image: Sorting]

In controller I get all the categories into single generic list in pretty much random unsorted manner

```
var categories = new List<Category>(this.categoryService.GetCategories())
```

Each category has 4 properties that matter here **Id**, **ParentCategoryId**, **SortOrder**, **Text**

**SortOrder** has to be applied only towards siblings on same level in the hierarchy and children have to be positioned always underneath their parent. **Text** has to change by prepending ".." for each level of depth.

I'd like this to be done properly with performance in mind, don't want to loop recursively through massive list multiple times.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: So what have you tried? And what is the problem you facing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might not be the most *performant* code, but should work for *OP*'s problem.

Since *OP* didn't explicitly define the data structure (model) in question, I'm going to assume it's something like this:

```
public class Category {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
  public int SortOrder { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

To sort a list of category (`List<Category>`) into a multilevel categories, we need a tree-like structure to hold the data.

First, I would extend the model (`Category` class) with new properties such as `Level` (to indicate the level-depth), `Children` (to hold the sub/child `Category`), and `DisplayText` (for displaying the category text according to its level):

```
public class CategoryNode : Category {
  public CategoryNode(Category category) {
    Id = category.Id;
    ParentCategoryId = category.ParentCategoryId;
    SortOrder = category.SortOrder;
    Text = category.Text;
  }

  public CategoryTree Children { get; set; }
  public int Level { get; set;}
  public string DisplayText { 
    get { 
      // OP wants two-dots prefix per level
      return string.Concat(new string('.', Level*2), Text); 
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: Depends of your preference, you could alter the `Category` class directly, instead of subclassing it into `CategoryNode`.*

Next, I would define a class to wrap the collection of `CategoryNode` called `CategoryTree`, it is a simple wrapper of `List<CategoryNode>` which expose an `IEnumerable` interace. I'd also add a `Flatten()` method inside `CategoryTree` which will flatten the tree-like structure into a single list. This method will come in handy for binding the data into a single-list (non-hierarchical) control such as `DropDownList` or `ListBox`. And last, I'd also add a static creation method called `Create()` to create an instance of `CatogoryTree` based on a given list of `Category`:

```
public class CategoryTree : IEnumerable<CategoryNode> {
  private List<CategoryNode> innerList = new List<CategoryNode>();

  public CategoryTree(IEnumerable<CategoryNode> nodes) {
    innerList = new List<CategoryNode>(nodes);  
  }

  public IEnumerator<CategoryNode> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return innerList.GetEnumerator();
  }

  System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return this.GetEnumerator();
  }

  public IEnumerable<CategoryNode> Flatten() {
    foreach(var category in innerList.OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder)) {
      yield return category;

      if (category.Children != null) {
        foreach(var child in category.Children.Flatten()) {
          yield return child;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static CategoryTree Create(
    IEnumerable<Category> categories, 
    Func<Category, bool> parentPredicate, 
    int level = 0) 
  {
    var nodes = categories
      .Where(parentPredicate)
      .OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder)
      .Select(item => new CategoryNode(item) { 
        Level = level,
        Children = Create(categories, o => o.ParentCategoryId == item.Id, level + 1)
      });

    return new CategoryTree(nodes);
  }
}
```

*Note: Again, arguably, you could just use `List<CategoryNode>` directly, extract the methods, and save yourself the hassle of creating a new class here. Your call.*

With all pieces in place I could now use the following code to convert a list of `Category` (`List<Category>`) into a multilevel list of `Category`, and flatten that list to bind it into a `DropDownList`:

```
...
var categories = new List<Category>(this.categoryService.GetCategories())

// assuming ParentCategoryId == 0 is the root category
var categoryTree = CategoryTree.Create(categories, o => o.ParentCategoryId == 0);

var model = new SomeViewModel();
model.Categories = new SelectList(categoryTree.Flatten(), , "Id", "DisplayText");

return View(model);
...    
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, Model.Categories)
...
```

---

Demo (using `Console.Out`): https://ideone.com/ejOfrr

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing a Dictionary structure?

As in:

```
Dictionary<Categories, List<T>> dictionary = new Dictionary<Categories, List<T>>();
```

This might conform to your requirements.

Further if you want a sorted Category structure the you can implement a SortedDictionary with Category as the Key & a corresponding List as Value.